# iam getting errors as follow Warning: include_once(C:/xampp/htdocs/timetable/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql

```
Warning: include_once(C:/xampp/htdocs/timetable/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\timetablegeneratormaster\timetable\index.php on line 4

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'C:/xampp/htdocs/timetable/header.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\timetablegeneratormaster\timetable\index.php on line 4
Warning: include_once(C:/xampp/htdocs/timetable/footer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\timetablegeneratormaster\timetable\index.php on line 80

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'C:/xampp/htdocs/timetable/footer.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\timetablegeneratormaster\timetable\index.php on line 80
```

Comment: You need to add more details.  Seems like your path is uncorrect

Comment: Isn't the message `No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\timetablegeneratormaster\timetable\index.php on line 4` clear?

Answer (score 0):

When including files that are in the same directory or to several levels higher or lower than the current file, use the `__DIR__` constant to get the path to these files.

If `header.php` and `footer.php` are in the same directory as `index.php`, use this code:

```php
include_once(__DIR__ . "/header.php");
include_once(__DIR__ . "/footer.php");
```

If they are in a subdirectory, e.g. `includes` then use the code:

```php
include_once(__DIR__ . "/includes/header.php");
include_once(__DIR__ . "/includes/footer.php");
```

However, if they were in another place, you use such code:

```php
include_once(__DIR__ . "/../../includes/another.php");
```

The `__DIR__` contains the name of the current directory where the php file is located in which the constant is used.